# How to Ignore Blank Cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzmDO.png)

Hi, row P, how do i change every number to 1. I dont want to add numbers to emty cells.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column next to column `P`.
In the cell of the second row in this new column put this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(P2:P<>"","1",))
```